# Linked List manual Alphabetical sorting

Tags: java

I am working with linkedlists at the moment in java. Our assignment was to create one from scratch, that sorts user input(Strings) into alphabetical order. I have been trying a lot of things, but none of the concepts I come up with seem to work. Any Advice/tips would be appreciated.

```
package linkedlist;
public class Linked {

    Node head;
    int listCount;    

    public Linked(){
        head = new Node(null);
        listCount = 0;
    }
    public void add(String data){
        Node linkedTemp = new Node(data);
        Node linkedCurrent = head;
        while (linkedCurrent.getNext() != null) {
                linkedCurrent = linkedCurrent.getNext();
                }
        linkedCurrent.setNext(linkedTemp);
        listCount++;

    }

    public void add2(String data){
        Node linkedTemp = new Node(data);
        Node linkedCurrent = new Node(get(1));

        if(listCount >= 1){ 

          while (linkedCurrent.getNext() != null){

              if(linkedCurrent.getData().compareTo(linkedTemp.getData()) <= 0){
                  linkedCurrent.setNext(linkedTemp);
                  listCount++;
                  break;
              }
              if(linkedCurrent.getData().compareTo(linkedTemp.getData()) >= 0)
                linkedCurrent = linkedCurrent.getNext();
        }
    }
    }

     public String toString() {
        Node linkedCurrent = head.getNext();
        String output = "";
        while (linkedCurrent != null) {
            output += "[" + linkedCurrent.getData().toString() + "]";
            linkedCurrent = linkedCurrent.getNext();
        }
        return output;
    }
     public String get(int index)
    {
        if (index <= 0)
            return null;

        Node linkedCurrent = head.getNext();
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
            if (linkedCurrent.getNext() == null)
                return null;

            linkedCurrent = linkedCurrent.getNext();
        }
        return linkedCurrent.getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for posting your code--what about it isn't working? Are you getting exceptions, or is it sorting the nodes incorrectly?

Comment: A bit of both. I frequently get NullPointers and I'm still not sure if I'm even on the right track for sorting it properly. I have been forbidden from using arrays to help sort it as well. I am trying to implement the sort into an add method at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except that the sort does not work, I think your code is OK. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Linked linked = new Linked();
    linked.add("data3");
    linked.add("data2");
    linked.add("data1");
    System.out.println( linked );

    System.out.println( linked.get(1) );
    System.out.println( linked.get(2) );
    System.out.println( linked.get(3) );
    System.out.println( linked.get(4) );
}
```

Above test code gives the output that meets our expectation.

```
[data3][data2][data1]
data3
data2
data1
null
```

But as I told you, the thing is that the sorting part of the problem is not solved. To solve the problem, I think you should modify the 'add' part of the code. Your `add` method does not consider the order of the inserted items.

```
public void add(String data){
    Node linkedTemp = new Node(data);
    Node linkedCurrent = head;
    Node linkedPrev = head;
    while ( linkedCurrent != null ) {
        if ( linkedCurrent.getData() != null && linkedCurrent.getData().compareTo(data) > 0 ) {
            break;              
        }
        linkedPrev = linkedCurrent;
        linkedCurrent = linkedCurrent.getNext();
    }
    linkedTemp.setNext( linkedPrev.getNext() );
    linkedPrev.setNext(linkedTemp);
    listCount++;
}
```

As your code using a 'null head' which contains a meaningless data, the added `if` block inside of the `while` statement checks if `linkedCurrent.getData()` is not null.

After the above modification to the `add` method, the output becomes:

```
[data1][data2][data3]
data1
data2
data3
null
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I implemented your modification and everything is running perfectly. It makes so much sense now that I see it and I can't believe I didn't figure it out. Actually now the third String in the list seems to having a bit of trouble. If I input: c, f, d, a, b, e. it outputs as abdefc

Comment: *correction* the first thing inputted is shoved to the end.

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences. I modified the answer. At the while statement, `while ( linkedCurrent.getNext() != null ) {` should be changed into `while ( linkedCurrent != null ) {`.

Comment: It's not an inconvenience at all. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this.